# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I made a web-application with Symfony2, and I'm using PUGX User Bundle and FosUserBundle to manage 2 different users.

This is one of the two user:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Entity
   * @ORM\Table(name="user_Operator")
   * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
   * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", message="Username already_used")
   * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", message="Email already_used")
   */
  class UserOperator extends User
  {
      /**
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
       */
      protected $id;

          /**
       * @ORM\PrePersist
       */
      public function setCreatedAtValue()
      {
          $this->addRole('ROLE_OPERATOR');
      }    
  }
```

When I try to register, I fill the form, submit, than appears:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\BitNami\wampstack-
5.4.23-0\frameworks\symfony\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-    
bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Model\User.php line 142
```

The line 142 is the following:

```
   135    public function addRole($role)
          {
              $role = strtoupper($role);
              if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
                  return $this;
              }

   142        if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
                  $this->roles[] = $role;
              }

              return $this;
          }
```

Don't know because I have this problem since I made an association @ORM\ManyToMany between User and Mission, that is another entity that here doesn't appear. Before this I hadn't this problem.

I use PUGXUser Bundle because it helps to easily manage two different kind of user. The User Entity is in my bundle, extends FosUserBundle..../Model/User.php and is extended by UserOperator and UserGroundStation.

The definition of the role is in the FosUserBundle.../Model/User.php:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $roles;
```

and the costruct is:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = array();
}
```

Comment: Initialize `$this->roles` as `= array();` in your class.

Comment: You should not use 2 bundles for 2 different users. The FOSUserBundle for example, gives you everything you need about user management.

Comment: Show `$roles` property definition, please. Is this a simple array or a Doctrine ArrayCollection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use:

```
if (is_array($this->roles)) {
    if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but now another problem appears. But I think is a copletely different thing. It shows: "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'salt' cannot be null"

Can you briefly explain which was the problem and why in a first moment was ok, and later no? I'm very new of php, and I neither know where to find information.

Comment: I solved the "second problem", calling         parent::__construct();
Thank you!

Comment: If the intention is to modify FOSUserBundle code, then this solution may break when code is updated.  Instead, place the modified `addRole()` function in `MyBundle\Entity\User`.

Comment: @GianniAlessandro `parent::__construct()` also would've solved your first problem at hand, as the parent class initializes `$roles`.

Comment: lots of thanks because above code working very well.

Answer (score 6):

`in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

For me, i solved this problem just with `parent::__construct()`; on my entity

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can code it in one line... nessesary if an array not always exists

```
if ( is_array($maybe_array) AND in_array($needle, $maybe_array) ) {...
```

because of the handling of the AND-clause your in_array will not be proved if is_array is false.

Answer (score 1):

It can also help to first check if the array is not empty. For example:

```
if (!empty($this->roles) && !in_array($role, $this->roles, true))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/*Item's lists */
    $items = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Coconut', 'Guava', 'Lemon', 'Mango');
/*Fruit's lists to be search in Items */
    $fruits = array('Apple', 'Coconut', 'Mango');
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (in_array($item, $fruits)) {
    $checked = "checked";
        } 
        else{
    $checked = "unchecked";
        }
   echo '< input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]"' . $checked . '  />';
   }
```